# how to access shopify Products via API without api-key and password?

Tags: shopify

i want to develop a chrome extension to see stats for any store which develop in shopify, can i access any store products without API-Key and Password in shopify?

Comment: What did you try already? Where do you struggle? What works, what doesn't?

Comment: before trying something i am searching about can i access shopify store products without api-key and passwords ? , i have google it but i did't see anything regarding my question that's why i ask here

Comment: You should clarify your question. What do you mean by "see some stats" when browsing in a shop admin? It is not clear at all what you are trying to accomplish, and any answer will almost surely be a small part of a bigger much more complex result.

Comment: like their monthly products sale to generate report and compare to other shopify stores same as shopify inspector.

Comment: shopify inspector is a chrome extension for shopify shops to see and compare shop statistics like monthly report and graphs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, you cant access products json without using api-key or permanent token of the store.
But still you want to access the product details you atleast needs the handler of the product.

Lets say your store is "abc.myshopify.com" and handler of your product is "xyz", then you can product json of xyz by HTTP GET call in following url

https://www.abc.myshopify.com/products/xyz.json

in general

```
https://www.[storename]/products/[product-handle].json
```

Comment: i have run this URL https://hu7sy-store.myshopify.com/products/product-2.json but it return nothing but if i open it browser where i already login to shopify it return data.

Comment: can you guide me how shopify inspector(chrome extension) make stats of any store without api-key and password.

Comment: @HassanShafique your store is not still published and its password protected. Once you will publish you will be able to access the data from the link.
Yes, you can get array of all products from [storename]/products.json once its been published. But you will just be able to read products. Editing or adding products will not be accessible.

Comment: it is running in browser but for curl request it is not running

Comment: I am not so familiar with curl. But the same thing is working fine with Java HTTP GET request.

Comment: ok thanks and one thing more products.json only return 30 products, can we increase number of products?

Comment: Shopify will only return 50 products at a time, I dont know why its displaying only 30 in yours. But there is a solution for that, you need to do pagination and its simple.
example for next set of products 
https://www.[storename]/products.json?page=2
you need to simply chang page number for each sets.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [Shopify StoreFront API](https://help.shopify.com/api/storefront-api).

It allows to get information of your shop from from your own website or custom app. Although it doesn't need a API Password, it needs a Api Key that doesn't need to be a secret.

The documentation says this (the first point is the important):

> Using the Storefront API, you can:
>
> - Fetch data about a single product or a collection of products to
>     display on any website or device.
> - Create unique checkout experiences
>     with full control over the shopping cart.
> - Create new customers or
>     modify existing ones, including address information.
> - Allow customers
>     to select unique product options.

Comment: can i get X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token for any store who has enable storefront?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way shopify will provide store details (product list) without api authentication.

For your requirement, I would suggest to create a shopify app which will sync all product details to your storage and you can access data from there.